# DPD auto and crosscorrelation

Tags: autocorrelation

I am trying to learn signal processing and digital pre-distortion.

http://www.altera.com/end-markets/wireless/advanced-dsp/predistortion/wir-digital-predistortion.html

I am currently trying to auto correlate the input signal and from this I make a matrix. I then get the coefficients for this matrix and use them with a LUT to help pre-distort the signal. I am having difficulty understanding what these coefficients represent? Why are they useful when added to the LUT. So the coefficients are used as a weight in those LUTs. Can anyone give me a pointer?

Same goes for the cross-correlation with the feedback, what do the coefficients from that vector represent?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please don't cross-post on stackexchange (Electrical Engineering and here). Choose the most appropriate site and if you don't get an answer, ask a moderator to migrate it somewhere else. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross-posted here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102126/dpd-auto-and-crosscorrelation